# I want to complete the verification of the Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am creating and hosting a web app with Google Apps Script(html). The screen of 'Unverified app screen' is displayed.
Google workspace is not used.
With over 100 users, access to the app is now blocked.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification?hl=en#applicability

I'm trying to request verification of the app by referring to the following article, but I'm stumbling on the confirmation of ownership of Apps Script in step 1.

※google cloud platform project has already been created, and is linked to the Apps script project.

Is there a way to check the ownership of a web page launched with Google Apps Script using the Google search console?

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents of the script into a new one? Also check that all the scopes are in the manifest explicitly

Answer (score 0):

They need to click on the unsafe link and authorize the script.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But I know what you pointed out.

The app no ​​longer even shows the Unverified app screen.
I'm guessing the app has hit the user limit.
So I tried Requesting verification.
However, I am in trouble because I cannot confirm the ownership of the web application hosted by Apps script on the search console.
The website is https://script.google.com/macros/s/~~~/exec.

Comment: Are you logged into multiple accounts if so get out of all of them except the one that created the script.  Go into the script editor and run some function.  Any function.  I actually  sometimes create a function that doesn't do anything just to get the verification screen and go past all of the warning and down to the bottom and verify it.  This will probably be scary for your users but if the wan't to run the script and they trust you then that's there only choice unless you wish to go through the verification process with google.